# Laravel Chunk Returning Few Data - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have about 2000 records in my database and i want to fetch them using view into my datatable.

When i run my code, i noticed my database is only showing 166 records. Why is that happening ?

**Controller**

```
 $chunks =  Items::
        where('is_active', 1)
        ->pluck('name','code','barcode','is_active')
        ->chunk(10);
        foreach ($chunks as $key => $chunk) {
            $chunks[$key] = array_values($chunk->toArray());
        }

     Log::info($chunks);
    return $chunks;
```

Comment: Can it be that some records have the field is_active != 1?

Comment: No, i have checked my database and every product is set to 1 for is_active column @Tiago

Comment: I implemented code like what you wrote, and it returning 2000 records, Please check your database is it really have 2000 items ? and does all of them ```is_active == 1```, you could test: ```Items::where('is_active', 1)->get()```

Comment: I have tested several times @RatebHabbab, i have 2000 records. I think the issue may be from the pluck

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? I can't get it to work under 8. Pluck accepts at most 2 values: column and key. You're passing in 4

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is related to the way you retrieve your data:

```php
 $chunks = Items::
        where('is_active', 1)
        ->pluck('name','code','barcode','is_active');
```

Here, you are misusing `pluck()`. This method returns an array (a Collection in this case but it's the same here) where the first argument is the value and the second argument is the key.

You are passing 4 parameters, the last two are useless.

Here is what's happening:

```php
 $chunks = Items::
        where('is_active', 1)
        ->pluck('name','code'); //removed the last two parameters, they are not used
```

`$chunks` is a Collection, where the key is the `code` and the value is the `name`.

A Collection, like an array, cannot have the same key multiple times. Then, if two users share the same `code`, the second user will "overwrite" the first one. The third will overwrite the second and so on.

At the end, you'll have a Collection where the number of items will be equal to the number of unique `code` that are active (`where('is_active', 1)`.

This why it fails.

How to fix this? Use `get()`, it does exactly what you expected pluck to do:

```php
$chunks =  Items::
        where('is_active', 1)
        ->get(['name','code','barcode','is_active']) //be careful, array here
        ->chunk(10);
        foreach ($chunks as $key => $chunk) {
            $chunks[$key] = array_values($chunk->toArray());
        }

     Log::info($chunks);
    return $chunks;
```